# Error in combining 2 SQL Queries together

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, inner-join

Please have a look at the below code

```
SELECT ongoing_portfolio.*,
Portfolio.Activation
FROM Ongoing_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
WHERE ongoing_portfolio.`idPortfolio`= 2 ORDER BY `Updated_Date` DESC LIMIT 4
```

---

```
SELECT SUM(`Transaction_Amount`) AS `Total`
FROM  `transactions`
WHERE `idPortfolio`= 2 AND `Transaction_TimeStamp` <= "2016-12-17"
```

Actually what I am trying to do in here is this.

1. Get the financial details of all the portfolios (first query).
2. Get the total transaction for the date mentioned as `Updated_Date` of the particular portfolio referred by the first query. (second query)

Now, I really need to do this in one query, so I tried below.

```
 SELECT ongoing_portfolio.*,
Portfolio.Activation,
SUM(Transactions.`Transaction_Amount`) AS `Total` WHERE `Transaction_TimeStamp` <= ongoing_portfolio.`Updated_Date`
FROM Ongoing_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
INNER JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.`idPortfolio` = Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio
WHERE ongoing_portfolio.`idPortfolio`= 2 ORDER BY `Updated_Date` DESC LIMIT 4
```

However this generates errors as it says

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `Transaction_TimeStamp` <= ongoing_portfolio.`Updated_Date`
FROM Ongoing_' at line 3
```

How can I make this one query successfully?

Comment: move `AND `Transaction_TimeStamp` <= "2016-12-17"` as  where condition and then add a `group by` before the order by, not sure about the grouping part since you have not specified about on which column grouping to be done and make sum as just sum(Transactions.Transaction_Amount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use where condition in retrieving column.
You can use if else or when condition for total.

```
    SELECT ongoing_portfolio.*,
        Portfolio.Activation,
        SUM(case when Transaction_TimeStamp` <= ongoing_portfolio.`Updated_Date` 
            then Transactions.`Transaction_Amount` end) AS `Total` FROM Ongoing_Portfolio
        INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
        INNER JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.`idPortfolio` = Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio
        WHERE ongoing_portfolio.`idPortfolio`= 2 group by 'Updated_Date' 
ORDER BY `Updated_Date` DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: I have made canges in query.I forgot to write end after case when just try it now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `Total` is wrong, seems like it is calculating some other portfolio transactions as well..Apart from that, I am only getting 1 result..

Comment: You need to do group by on column then you will get multiple entries.

Comment: Yeah I tried it, Thanks!. There is another issue, will post a new question.